# apply fourier shift theorem to complex signal

Tags: r, time, signal-processing, fft, phase

Im trying to apply the [fourier phase shift theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem) to a complex signal in R. However, only the magnitude of my signal shifts as I expect it. I think it should be possible to apply this theorem to complex signals, so probably I make an error somewhere. My guess is that there is an error in the frequency axis I calculate.

How do I correctly apply the fourier shift theorem to a complex signal (using R)?

```
i = complex(0,0,1)
t.in = (1+i)*matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
n.shift = 5

#the output of fft() has the mean / 0 frequency at the first element
#it then increases to the highest frequency, flips to negative frequencies
#and then increases again to the negative frequency closest to 0
N = length(t.in)
if (N%%2){#odd
  kmin = -(N-1)/2
  kmax = (N-1)/2
} else {#even
  kmin = -N/2
  kmax = N/2-1
  #center frequency negative, is that correct?
}

#create frequency axis for fft() output, no sampling frequency or sample duration needed
k = (kmin:kmax)
kflip = floor(N/2)
k = k[c((kflip+1):N,1:kflip)]
f = 2*pi*k/N

shiftterm = exp( -i*n.shift*f )

T.in = fft(t.in)
T.out = T.in*shiftterm
t.out = fft(T.out, inverse=T)/N

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(Mod(t.in),col="green"); 
plot(Mod(t.out), col="red");
plot(Arg(t.in),col="green");
plot(Arg(t.out),col="red");
```

As you can see the magnitude of the signal is nicely shifted, but the phase is scrambled. I think the negative frequencies are where my error is, but I cant see it.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

The questions about fourier phase shift theorem I could find:

[real 2d signal in python](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10250/how-to-circularly-shift-a-signal-by-a-fraction-of-a-sample)

[real 2d signal in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811083/fourier-shift-theorem-matlab)

[real 1d signal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885972/shift-theorem-in-discrete-fourier-transform)

[math question about what fourier shift does](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099582/discrete-fourier-transform-shift-by-fraction-of-a-sample)

But these were not about complex signals.

Comment: If the magnitude is zero (to machine precision) then the phase doesn't tell you much. Is the phase of the 6th term correct?

Comment: @Steve Did not see this coming, youre right! Do you think I can use my shifted signal as is, or should I set it to 0 where `Mod(t.out) < .Machine$double.eps` ? Also, care to make this an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: Perhaps [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38234072/5358968) would be a good candidate for marking as duplicate rather than deleting the question?

Comment: No that is not about the phase shift theorem, but about rearranging the fft elements for use by certain functions. There are some similar questions but none of them about complex signals. Wait I`ll add some links to the post.

Comment: Feel free to put your research together as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

As Steve suggested in the comments, I checked the phase on the 6th element.

```
> Arg(t.out)[6]
[1] 0.7853982
> Arg(t.in)[1]
[1] 0.7853982
```

So the only element that has a magnitude (at least one order of magnitude higher than the `EPS`) does have the phase that I expected.

**TL;DR** *The result from the original approach in the question was already correct, we see the Gibbs Phenomenon sliding by.*

---

**Just discard low magnitude elements?**

If ever the phase of elements that should be zero will be a problem I can run `t.out[Mod(t.out)<epsfactor*.Machine$double.eps] = 0` where in this case `epsfactor` has to be `10` to get rid of the '0' magnitude elements.

Adding that line before plotting gives the following result, which is what I expected to get beforehand. However, the 'scrambled' phase might actually be accurate in most cases as I'll explain below.

[image]

**The original result really was correct**

Just setting low magnitude elements to `0` does not make the phase of the shifted signal more intuitive however. This is a plot where I apply a 4.5 sample shift, the phase is still 'scrambled'.

[image]

**Applying fourier shift equivalent to downsmapling shifted fourier interpolation**

It occurred to me that applying a non-integer number of elements phase shift is equivalent to fourier interpolating the signal and then downsample the interpolated signal at points between the original elements. Since the vector I used as input is an impulse function, the fourier interpolated signal is just not well behaved. Then the signal after applying the fourier phase shift theorem can be expected to have exactly the phase that the fourier interpolated signal has, as seen below.

[image]

**Gibbs Ringing**

Its just at the discontinuities where phase is not well behaved and where small rounding errors might cause large errors in the reconstructed phase. So not really related to low magnitude but to not well defined fourier transform of the input vector. This is called [Gibbs Ringing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#The_square_wave_example), I could use low-pass [filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts#Low-pass_filter) with a [gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) filter to decrease it.

[image]

***Questions related to fourier interpolation and phase shift***

[symbolic approach in R to estimate fourier transform *error*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802649/returning-traditional-notations-of-functions-in-the-context-of-fourier-interpo)

[non integer signal shift by use of linear interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830878/shift-the-elements-of-a-vector-by-non-integer-shift-in-matlab)

[downsampling complex signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43308745/how-to-downsample-fourier-complex-values)

[fourier interpolation application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323403/interpolation-through-fourier-space-padding)

[estimating sub-sample shift between two signals using fourier transforms](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/estimate-delay-of-a-known-signal-delayed-by-sub-sample-resolution/25686#25686)

[estimating sub-sample shift between two signals without interpolation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25836/is-sub-sampling-delay-estimation-possible-without-interpolation)